# The configuration system failed to initialize, when using a local database

Tags: c#, localdb

I'm trying to use input from a windows form app to enter into a localdb, however when I send the data to the database it returns "the config system failed to initialize".

```
try
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["database"].ConnectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();person newPerson = new person(FirstNameBox.Text, phoneBox.Text, emailBox.Text, LastNameBox.Text);
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Person (FirstName, LastName, Email,Phone)
                        VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @Phone)";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", newPerson.getFirstName());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", newPerson.getLastName());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", newPerson.getEmail());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", newPerson.getPhone());

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    if (!ValidateForm())
       return;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName,
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
```

and this is the `app.config` part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="database" 
         connectionString=" Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Midterm\Midterm\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"></add>
</connectionStrings>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Midterm.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
```

Comment: Can you include your whole app.config? It sounds like it's incorrectly formatted.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Inspect the exception object in the debugger (or ToString the exception rather than just displaying the Message property). Typically, for this kind of error, there is an inner exception with more details.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious issue I'm seeing here is that your app.config is specifying a  `<connectionString>` section, where it should be `<connectionStrings>` (note the **s**).

You may want to provide your entire app.config as there may be other syntax/configuration issues that prevent `ConfigurationManager` from loading your app.config.

**Edit for updated app.config**:

Your app.config file is incorrectly formatted. `<configSections>` shouldn't be the root element of the file (it should be `<configuration>`).

The MSDN documentation for [ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows an example of what a app.config file should be formatted like.

But, in short, the `<connectionStrings>` element (and the other elements such as `<startup>`) should be a child element of `<configuration>`.

What your app.config should be like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    *** ADD YOUR <add> LINES HERE ***
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: ok I tried editing the tags to <connectionStrings> but it still gave the same error.

Comment: I've updated my response to clarify some other issues with your app.config that would be causing your problems.